# Website URL only displays domain name and not the subpages

Tags: php

When I access my website at `www.example.com`, I receive the correct page.  When I click on a link that accesses `www.example.com/somepage.php`, the server loads the new page correctly, but the URL bar still says `www.example.com`.  In addition, the web pages do not show the <title> specified in the HTML.

Could this have something to do with my using a URL Frame instead of a URL redirect through Namecheap?

Comment: Sure, that might be. Just check the html source your browser offers.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean.  A screenshot of the config is below:
http://puu.sh/iG7SF/1158c81460.png

Answer (score 0):

You probably just linked the domain to your website host. If you have a decent host you should be able to park the domain name in your cpanel. If you will tell me your host I will give you more information.

```
NameVirtualHost *:80

<VirtualHost *:80>
    DocumentRoot /www/docs/dummy-host.example.com
    ServerName dummy-host.example.com
    ServerAlias www.dummy-host.example.com
    ErrorLog @rel_logfiledir@/dummy-host.example.com-error_log
    CustomLog @rel_logfiledir@/dummy-host.example.com-access_log common
</VirtualHost>
```

Comment: I host the content myself on a machine running a LAMP stack.
The domain name and forward come from Namecheap.
I will link a picture of my config page shortly.

Comment: The config page looks as follows (with my URL and host IP omitted):
http://puu.sh/iG7SF/1158c81460.png

Comment: Try adding <VirtualHost foldername.tld:80> to the top of your LAMP config file

Comment: That line exactly?
And you mean `httpd.conf`, right?

Comment: Change foldername.tld to fit your domain. It should be the httpd.conf

Comment: And since apache listens on 8080, should I be using that instead of 80?

Comment: Yeah sorry, I forgot to change that, it should be 8080

Comment: I'm still trying to figure out where it's supposed to go.  I'm using the default config so far.  I've changed values as I've needed.  I'll pastebin it, but I understand if that's not something you want to sort through.  I've removed most of the commenting:

Comment: I think it should go to the first line

Comment: If my domain name were `example.com` would it then be:

`<VirtualHost example.com:8080>`?

Comment: Yes, and then you should restart the server. BTW are you on windows or linux?

Comment: Currently testing on Windows with Xampp.
When I use that as the first line, apache fails to start.

Comment: Then delete that line from config file and go to apache/conf/extra/httpd-vhosts.conf and paste the code that is in my answer.

Comment: Otherwise I found some tutorials online:

Comment: Still won't work.  I have added the entry as follows: http://pastebin.com/15j8TAvs

Comment: I'll give those a try.  Thank you.

Comment: I managed to get the VirtualHost working.  However, I still do not get the name of subpages in the URL.  I also don't get the titles of the pages.

Comment: Well, only other suggestion I have is that you could buy a host or get one for free. Freezoy and x10Hosting have worked splended for me, and its really easy to park the domain. You can find all the information in the cpanel once you register.